# Concatenate Variable to file path

Tags: cmd

So Ive got the following code to write the append the date %ldt% to an file.
What is wrong?

```
@echo off
for /F "usebackq tokens=1,2 delims==" %%i in (`wmic os get LocalDateTime /VALUE 2^>NUL`) do if '.%%i.'=='.LocalDateTime.' set ldt=%%j
set ldt=%ldt:~0,4%-%ldt:~4,2%-%ldt:~6,2% %ldt:~8,2%:%ldt:~10,2%:%ldt:~12,6%

echo %ldt% ::working

copy file.txt "file[%ldt%].txt" ::not working
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set ldt=%ldt:~0,4%-%ldt:~4,2%-%ldt:~6,2% %ldt:~8,2%:%ldt:~10,2%:%ldt:~12,6%
           yyyy   -    mm    -    dd         hh    :     mm    :    ss.cs
                                                   ^           ^
```

You can not include a colon in a file name. Replace them with other character

Comment: it works, but when I try copying the file from an higher folder it doesnt work: `copy "../file.txt" "file%ldt%.txt"`

Comment: `copy "..\file.txt" "file%ldt%.txt"` The path separator is `\ `, not `/`. In some cases windows will accept `/` but as it will sometimes be considered a switch indicator, it is not a good practice to use it as a path separator